# Export .svg icon with padding from Sketch

Tags: svg, sketch-app

When I export an icon as an .svg that contains padding, the padding seems to get lost when saved.

I have this icon with a 1px padding on the sides:
[image]

When I export that icon as a .svg, and import it again, it has lost it's padding. How do I preserve this?

Extra information: I'm using the [SVGO compressor](https://github.com/BohemianCoding/svgo-compressor) plugin to compress .svg's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what the compressor does exactly, but one simple way would be adding a transparent rectangle to the artboard that covers the whole area.

Comment: That would be a solution, but I don't really like these kind of hacks

Comment: Sketch (unlike Adobe Illustrator, Affinity Designer or Inkscape) doesn't respect the viewBox size as artboard. It imports the inner SVG content only. So this hack is the only option I know of.

Comment: That sucks. I'll wait for a bit and then mark your answer as the correct one

Answer (score 1):

Add your icon on a new artboard of your desired size, and export the artboard itself as SVG. This works for me.